# lifetime of a physically disconnected tcp socket without keepalive

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

On a TCP connection without the keep-alive option, if I physically disconnect the wire - so no FIN/ACK possibility, will this socket happily accept all my application data, put it in the send buffer and try to send it forever?

And if not, when and how it dies = which errors will be returned to my application sending small chunks of data? we talk Linux and c.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the send side, it would fill up the send buffer since it cannot send the data to the client. The outgoing packets (as much allowed by the receive window and available space in the send buffer would simply sit in the send buffer and TCP would end up retransmitting them.

URL: http://linux.die.net/man/2/send

If the socket is blocking, then the `send()` call would simply block and the application would end up waiting for this call. If the socket is non-blocking, then the send() call would return -1 and set the errno to EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK.

Setting SO_KEEPALIVE is certainly the main option for such sockets. In addition, you could also play around with tcp_retries1 and tcp_retries2 values mentioned in  /proc/sys/net/ipv4/. When the sender kills the connection due to tcp_retries2 limit reached, the next blocking call would return a value of -1 and the errno would be set to ETIMEDOUT. Please note that these options are applied globally to all sockets on the box -- so we should use it with care.

Comment: so to cut long story short you suggest that the socket will live until next reboot, whereas the answer above suggests that the socket will be reset based on ACKs timeout (provided that I pulled the wire from receiver, and sender's physical layer sends the packets out).

Comment: Since this side of the socket is sending data, tcp_retries 2 (on Linux) should kick in and kill the connection. If the side has no data to send, then it will continue to live until you reboot the box.

Comment: If the connection is killed by "tcp_retries 2", then the next non-blocking I/O call on the connection file descriptor returns what?

Comment: You would get a returned value of -1 and the errno would be set to ETIMEDOUT. I have also updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the socket is sending, (1) eventually the send buffer will fill up, so the next send call would block, and (2) eventually TCP would time out the send attempts due to receiving no ACKS and reset the connection, and deliver an error to the next send call.

Comment: it's unblocking mode. If the error based on ACK timeout, the the mode isn't quite relevant, is it? The question is - which error send/write eventually returns?

Comment: Besides, is send buffer filling up any relevant to ACK timeouts?

Comment: @wick, this answer is exactly the one to your question. After you unplug the cable, the app keeps sending data until the send-buffer is filled up, then the next send call is blocked (this is the 1st point in the answer). Under the hood, while the app is blocked, kernel keeps retransmitting the data in the send-buffer until time is out (because no ACK),then kernel deliver an error to the send call that is being blocked (this is the 2nd point in the answer), and the error is usually ETIMEDOUT or EHOSTUNREACH.

Comment: @user207421, I do have a question for you. when you say `reset the connecton`, you mean the kernel will eventually remove the connection? the connection will be gone? all the data in the send-buffer will be dropped?

Answer (score 0):

Without doing anything, the socket will keep open forever if no FIN is recieved. You can test this even without unplugging the cable: by firewalling the port after the connection has been established.

You need to use the keep alive feature of the linux kernel to *clean up* such connections. Check this [article](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/usingkeepalive.html)

Comment: This is untrue if the application keeps sending forever as stated in the question.

Comment: On this particular occasion I would actually prefer the socked lived forever, so it's fine. However, EJP above suggests that the socket will be eventually reset by kernel based on ACKs timeout. Would you agree?

Comment: @wich I must admit I'm not sure. What have you observed in your tests?

Comment: @EJP do you mean the send buffer has to be 100% full to signal kernel to consider ACKs timeouts as grounds for the socket resetting?

Comment: There has to be something in it that TCP has already tried to send for error detection to be possible. If it's full, `send()` will block so that the error is detected synchronously. If it isn't, any given `send()` may or may not encounter an existing error condition.

Comment: @EJP So if the send buffer has data but not full, the error is detected, and the connection is reset by kernel. Then the next non-blocking I/O call on this file descriptor in my application returns what? just EBADF?

Comment: @wick I should reword all this. If there is something in the send buffer that can't be sent, TCP will eventually time out on sending and reset the connection, and eventually deliver ECONNRESET to the next I/O call on the socket. Not EBADF: that would indicate that the socket had been closed, which only the application can do.

Comment: @wick Unless you have explicitly enabled keep alives as mentioned in my answer, the kernel will not clean up such connections.